# Check exit status of main

Tags: java

I am invoking the main class of a .class contained in the same folder from my Java code. That main is void, and I want to check whether it was successful or not by checking its exit status:

```
    ...
    String[] arguments = new String[]{"a", "b"};
    AnotherClass.main(arguments);
    ...
```

Any idea on how, being that AnotherClass.main(arguments); does not return anything?

Thank you.

Comment: Other than for startup, `main` is a perfectly normal method. What sort of "exit status" are you thinking of? Perhaps you should try to catch an exception?

Comment: You will only get exit status if you call another application at the system level, such as using Runtime.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even better idea -- instead of trying to call a main method, instead create a method in your other class called testMain() which does the same thing as main except it returns the exit code instead of exiting.

---

System.exit() called in that main method will shut down your entire program. You want to run the other main in another thread and find the exit code for that thread.

Build the other program (name the jar AnotherClass.jar), add the jar to your path and try this:

```
int exitCode;
try {
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java AnotherClass.jar",new String[]{"arg1","arg2"});
    exitCode = process.waitFor();
    System.out.println(exitCode);
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("IO Error: " + e);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    System.out.println("Inturrupted: " + e);
}
```

---

**EDIT: The following will not work at all; System.exit() kills all threads.**

This code will run another main method in a new thread, and when it exits it will not harm your current program.

```
Thread anotherProgram = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        AnotherClass.main(new String[]{"foo","bar"});
    }
});
anotherProgram.start();
```

Comment: Would love to see an example. To my knowledge a Thread doesn't have an exit code.

Comment: Well process but if you want to run another program inside of your program (I have no idea why) then you could multithread it.

Comment: If you use a process rather than Thread, there is an exit code to collect - you will need to assemble a Java command line execution. Have a look at `java.lang.ProcessBuilder`.

Comment: If it's just run inside another thread, the whole application will still exit (all threads, including the originating one that spawned the `anotherProgram` one in your example), so there would still be nothing left to collect it. Using `ProcessBuilder` you are creating a separate OS process, which then allows Java to access the exit code when the child process finishes.

Comment: What about the process?

Comment: @AnubianNoob your new example also won't work, as you can't execute a class name.

Comment: @MrPotes if you build it and add it to your path then you execute the name of the jar right? Not necassarily the class name? Or am I completely mistaken?

Comment: @AnubianNoob, I don't think you can even do that - although it would depend on the OS. Generally when you 'run' a JAR file by double clicking on it, you're actually running a shell extension that does `java myjar.jar` under the hood.

Comment: @MrPotes The what about executing "java myjar.jar" would that work?

Comment: @AnubianNoob yep, as long as `AnotherClass` is declared as the `Main-Class` in the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`

Comment: Thank you to all of you. I'm going to try this out and see how it goes.

Comment: @user2891462 tell me how it goes; I've never used processes.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the exit code parameter to `System.exit(int status)`, you cannot access it, as when it is called by some part of the `main` method (or subsequently executed code), your application is exited, and so there is nothing left running to get at the code.

The only way to check the exit code of an application is using the OS, e.g. the `$?` environment variable in unix tells you the exit code of the last application to terminate in that session.

Edit: Here's an example using `ProcessBuilder` to do so:

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder(System.getProperty("java.home")+"/bin/java", "fully.qualified.package.to.AnotherClass").start();
Integer exitCode = null;
while (exitCode == null) {
  try {
    exitCode = p.waitFor();
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // handle e
  }
}
```

Comment: You might also have to add classpath, and any other JVM arguments to the Process as separate arguments.